# How do I rotate a view in Interface Builder?

Tags: interface-builder

I realize this is a painfully noob question but I just don't know what to do.

I'm trying to rotate my view in Interface Builder, and everyone refers to the rotate icon in the top right of the view.

My Interface Builder doesn't have this icon. See screenshot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to enable this in preferences or something? I'm using Interface Builder 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just alter the dimensions of the view. You will have to create a new one and connect it as an IBOutlet of the correct objects, but make it's dimensions 480x320 instead of 320x480.

Comment: Alter the dimensions of the window, or add a new view and alter those dimenions? I'm setting orientation to landscape in the code and that works successfully; however, all images and such are rotated 90 degrees.